# ¿Cómo agregar datos de una consulta al form de registro en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

se puede mandar una variable a la vista del registro de usuario de Laravel?? estoy buscando y probando pero no encuentro nada. Dentro del formulario de registro quiero añadir un select de países que lo saca de la base de datos, normalmente las consultas se hacen en el controlador, pero aquí no se donde o como hacerlas.

Esto es lo que quiero añadir al formulario de registro:

```
<select class="form-control myinputs" name="pais" id="pais" required>
    @foreach ($paises as $pais)
       <option value="{{ $pais->codigo }}"> {{ $pais->pais }}</option> 
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: He ampliado un poco más @BetaM

Comment: Si perdona, correcto utilizo el auth de laravel

Comment: Si como puedo consultar a la base de datos desde la vista de register.

Comment: Para dejarlo más claro, donde tengo que hacer la consulta a la base de datos para poder consultar en la vista de registro `@paises`  @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

1. El controlador `RegisterController.php` se vale de un *trait* llamado `RegistersUsers`, (dicho trait se encuentra en esta ubicación **`..\vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\RegistersUsers.php`**)<sup>1</sup> para ejecutar el método `showRegistrationForm` el cual se encarga de invocar a la vista de registro.
2. Como **no veo conveniente** llevar una consulta de modelos directo a ese *trait*, lo que podemos hacer es *anular* su comportamiento y declararlo de nuevo en el controlador pero personalizado respondiendo a nuestras necesidades
3. Invocamos al modelo por su namespace
4. Entonces enviamos adjuntos a la vista de `auth.register` los datos obtenidos de nuestra consulta

Propuesta:

```
use App\Pais;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    /*
       Resto del código del controlador
    */

    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register', ["paises" => Pais::all()]);
    }
}
```

- <sup>1</sup> La ubicación exacta puede depender en razón de que versión de [paquete laravel-ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui) se esté utilizando, en el caso de esta respuesta es sobre la versión 3 del mismo.

Comment: Perdona @BetaM como hago esto que dices? `anular su comportamiento` y la propuesta que me dices, lo meteria en mi controlador habitual?? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Funciona perfecto!!! muchas gracias @BetaM